# How can I get last inserted Counter_id from Couchbase bucket?

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

How can I get last inserted Counter_id from Couchbase bucket ? So that I can increment a value from last inserted id + 1. I am using Couchbase java-client 2.5.5.

Comment: I don't know `couchbase` but I assume there's an auto-increment or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

To select the highest current value of field counter_id in the documents stored in the test bucket, you can run this N1QL query.

```
SELECT MAX(counter_id) FROM test
```

Then add 1 to the value.

The problem is that doing that won't work correctly if you have any realistic concurrency at all because of interleaving of queries. In that case, if you just need unique values, I suggest you use UUIDs, which are unique with high probability. I'm confident Java has some sort of library for generating UUIDs; it has everything else.

If you want to generate a UUID() from within N1QL itself, you can do that too, using the UUID() function.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/metafun.html

Alternately, you can use a counter document, as explained here:
https://blog.couchbase.com/using-autonumber-in-couchbase/

Comment: I am getting null value when I executed the above query. [
  {
    "$1": null
  }
]

Comment: If there are no documents with a counter_id field, the result of the aggregate is null.

Comment: Counter_id is not a field, I used counter to increase auto number for DocumentId in couchbase. Refer here https://blog.couchbase.com/using-autonumber-in-couchbase/

Comment: OK, so you have a document with id "counter_id" and a value that is a number. That value will not be included in the aggregate query; the aggregate query is looking through the values in fields named "counter_id", and that's different from documents named "counter_id". Different concepts. If you want to retrieve the value of the counter_id document using N1QL, you can use this query: `select * from test use keys "counter_id"` .

Comment: select * from test use keys "automic" in my case. but I tried with counter_id while creating documents using counter, getting the following error.. "Exception: 
com.couchbase.client.java.error.TranscodingException: Could not decode document with ID counter_id"

Comment: long nextIdNumber = bucket.counter("atomic", 1, 1).content(); //this works fine                    
                                                                                                                     
long nextIdNumber = bucket.counter("counter_id", 1, 1).content(); // returns com.couchbase.client.java.error.TranscodingException: Could not decode document with ID counter_id

Comment: My best guess is that after you run the query, the Java layer is trying to convert the result into Java objects of some sort, and doesn't know how to do it. That wouldn't be too surprising with a document that's just a number. Try retrieving the document using the KV functions.

Comment: Thank you @Johan Larson! I will check and let you know.. :)